# Spring: Error dump shown in debug level

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, log4j, spring-4

I'm using Spring 4.0.5

I have injected a bean reference as a property, but the source bean was commented.
My log level was warn, so I couldn't see debug messages.

In execution time, application didn't show error dumps, but did not work properly, and ended very quickly.
I changed the level to debug, and the next exception stack has been logged:

```
2015-10-08 11:37:01 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.rollbackOnException(TransactionTemplate.java:162)] Initiating transaction rollback on application exceptionorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.myItemProcessor' defined in class path resource [my-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'MyItemProcessorClass#741b31f2' of type [MyItemProcessorClass] while setting bean property 'delegates' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyItemProcessorClass#741b31f2' defined in class path resource [my-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dumpTransitosChecker' while setting bean property 'dumpTransitosChecker'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myCustomChecker' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:343)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:187)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.process(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$1.doWithRetry(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:225)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:193)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:217)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.transform(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:290)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyItemProcessorClass#741b31f2' defined in class path resource [my-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myCustomChecker' while setting bean property 'myCustomChecker'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myCustomChecker' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myCustomChecker' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 37 more
```

This exception, shown in debug level, has masked the error.
Is this log dump right? Or am I doing something wrong configuring log4j?

Any comment is very appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**: As Rossi Robinsion requested, here are the config files.

Obviously, reference to a commented bean is my mistake, but I was testing lot of things. The main issue is that the debug message with an error stack.

Thanks again.

Bean config file:

```
<!--
<bean id="myCustomChecker" class="com.mypackage.check.impl.TrueDumpTransitosCheck" scope="prototype" />
-->
<!--
<bean id="myCustomChecker" class="com.mypackage.check.impl.CorporateDumpTransitosCheck" scope="prototype" />
-->

...

<bean id="myDumpBean" class="com.mypackage.impl.DumpBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="checker"        ref="myCustomChecker" />
    ...
</bean>
```

log4j.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<appender name="main_log_file"
    class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/home/userapp/logs/app.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="20000000" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="WARN" />

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%n%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] [%l] %m" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<category name="com.mypackage">
    <priority value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="main_log_file" />
</category>

<root>
    <level value="WARN" />
</root>
```

Comment: Can you provide the Spring configuration?

Comment: @RossiRobinsion, thank you for your answer. I have included the config files by editing the main message. Thanks.

Comment: So you are trying to inject myCustomChecker bean into MyItemProcessor class. The bean def for myCustomChecker seems commented out? Its not finding myCustomChecker bean. Make sure, this bean is defined in the config so other beans can ref this.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion ,  thank you for your answer. It's true, and that was my mistake: ref beans must be defined, ok. But that's not the issue. The current problem is that, in this context, Spring dumps an error stack with debug category in log file. So, maybe I was supposing something wrong, but I expect an error stack was written in log file with error category (I changed to debug level desperately, and then, the posted error stack was shown). I don't know if it's an issue with Spring, or something wrong in my config, or anything else. Thanks again.